# I've broken my new MacBook Pro (with touchbar) like this, do I have to repair it?

Tags: macbook-pro, warranty

I am not sure whether this is a good question for this place. But I'd still like to have a try. It's anyway an "Apple question". If it's not a good place, I hope someone can let me know where should I go.

Here is my question:

I've broken my new MBP (the 2016 version with touchbar) like this:

[image]

Here is a high-quality photo:

[image]

Do I HAVE TO have it repaired?

I'm living in a place far away from Apple Store in the city so I'd like to get some online help before I make the decision to drive to downtown.

Thanks very much for any kind of tips.

Comment: Ugh - I can't imagine how this made you feel - I'm a little bummed just looking at the new hardware with that crack, but it looks like you didn't damage the actual display housing and it's a purely cosmetic covering that was damaged.

Comment: Apple IS NOT going to cover, under the standard warranty, the accidental damage you caused! You WILL have to pay for the repair! Make sure you backup you data before taking it to be repaired.

Comment: If you feel adventurous you could probably do the repair yourself. I would assume the screen frame itself can be obtained quite cheap from eBay - you'll just have to install your display panel in it.

Comment: @AndréBorie the problem is that the whole assembly is laminated and glued shut, as in theory it makes for a neat and strong assembly for such a thin screen. Replacing any of it will be very hard, and this is why most repair places ( and Apple ) replace the whole screen assembly.

Comment: You could try one of those windshield resin/epoxy fillers intendee for minor windscreen damage. It won't fix anything but at least it will be sealed.

Comment: @AndréBorie, that would also probably void the warranty even for damage that *would* have been covered by Apple.

Comment: This is why Apple is removing the jack

Comment: @Dan what do you mean by jack?

Comment: Apple may not pay, but that is a serious engineering flaw. It should have been caught by QC. I'd cover the shattered area with duct tape, to keep the cracks from growing and to remind me of what a shoddy job Apple did on an expensive product.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You certainly don't need to repair it unless you can't use the device. It's a minor safety hazard until you contain any broken glass, but gravity or a toothpick to dislodge any fragments and then some clear tape should handle that. If you want to put a little black electrical tape over the aluminum inside and then use thin clear tape to make the surface smooth - that would be the advanced level patch I'd recommend.

Neither the one year warranty nor AppleCare extension / expansion of the warranty is intended to cover that sort of damage, but I would still call Apple's phone or web support if you aren't going to be in the area of a store in the next week. Ask Apple what your options are, but be prepared if they don't offer to pay to repair the damage.

Once you have a quote (assuming it's not covered), check with your form of payment. Many US credit cards come with accident protection for new purchases - you might be covered under some sort of protection / insurance to pay whatever cost Apple might charge to repair it.

At that point, you can revisit if you're OK with the tape covering it and know what your options are if the cracks spread or if the hinges were damaged when the pressure built up before the glass gave in and cracked. I don't think that's the case since your photos show that the glass had no backing right where your item was placed and there's no evidence of deformation on the aluminum - so this might be a oops you can live with if you don't want to pay the cost for a new display repair and everything else works properly. All indications are this is cosmetic damage and can be patched well enough to keep further dust from invading the display housing if there's even a path from that lower cover to the main display space.

Comment: Thanks very much for such detailed answer. I just called them and they told me that this kind of physical damage is not covered by Apple Care.

I don't think there's any safety problem but I'm worried whether this "hole" would make some dust to get in and break my screen.

Anyway, I think it's quite necessary to put a clear tape on it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Credit card protection is for manufacturer defects or failures, not negligent damage like this

Comment: @smci Some credit cards will cover accidental damage, loss, theft, etc...,  at least up to certain limits. Some will not. It's worth checking to see what terms apply.

Comment: In addition, some home insurance policies also cover accidental damage. A few years back I had a whole MacBook Pro (well out of warranty) replaced in this way (and they even gave me the option of paying the difference for the highest spec model).

Comment: Accidental is one thing, negligent is another, though.

Answer (score 4):

I would try to make it to an Apple Store before the 1 year AppleCare coverage expires.

But you don't HAVE to repair that. I know someone who put a piece of scotch tape over their cracked glass touchpad and is still using their computer.

I would at least tape it up so the cracks have a harder time expanding.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite remember whether I've bought the 1 year AppleCare. Is there any place I can confirm that?

Comment: Go [this Apple page](https://checkcoverage.apple.com) for AppleCare coverage. You will need the serial number of the device.

Comment: ^check there, but I think every computer comes with the 1 year and you have to purchase the 3 year. Maybe that varies in different countries.

Comment: It doesn't really matter - you should get it to Apple as soon as possible. Neither the warranty nor AppleCare is intended to cover cosmetic or physical damage from an external source. Apple still may empathize or offer to cover the repair, so the sooner you go and the more humble you are - the more chance empathy will have a chance to override the "WHAT IS NOT COVERED BY THIS WARRANTY?" section of the hardware warranty at http://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/products/

Comment: @bmike I agree not to be arrogant and not to expect something one is not entitled to, but being “humble” towards a company one has just given thousands of dollars/euros/pounds seem a little too much, doesn't it?

Comment: @DaG you're right, Humble is the wrong term for what I had in mind. Polite, patient, ask to understand options is what I was aiming for. I personally wouldn't ask Apple to pay for the repair and would ask to understand the risks to letting it go unprepared after getting the quote.

Answer (score 4):

That is the glass cover not the actual screen.  At the bottom the screen is not behind the glass as room is required for the connectors.

The glass is not likely to crack and very little dust will get in. Dust would not harm the screen.  But cover it with tape would still be a good practice.

The glass alone is not very expensive but I will would not bother to replace it.
The labor cost is more than the cost of the glass and replaced is never better than the original install.

If you need to replace the screen then go ahead and replace the glass at that time.